# Installing rosserial on Raspbian with ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, rosserial, ros-hydro, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT: Solved, working rosserial connection between the pi and arduino following the instructions on http://wiki.jigsawrenaissance.org/ROS_on_RaspberryPi**

With both a Raspberry Pi Model A & B, I successfully installed ros hydro following the ros wiki *ROSberryPi/Setting up Hydro on RaspberryPi* but I haven't successfully installed rosserial yet.

I've tried following the *1.1 Broken Packages* section with the following commands:

```
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https:// github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial
$ cd ..
$ rosdep install  --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy
```

But rosdep fails here saying:

```
pi@rpiA ~/ros_catkin_ws $ rosdep install  --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy

executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-nav-msgs]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-nav-msgs
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-nav-msgs] failed
```

I'm trying to get an idea of what steps I could take to fix this, not sure where to start.

**EDIT - 2/5/2014 00:11**

Following suggestion to add missing packages (well I feel silly)

```
$ git clone https:// github.com/ros/common_msgs.git
$ cd ..
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy
...
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-tf]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-tf
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y ros-hydro-tf] failed
```

One down, tf next

```
$ git clone https:// github.com/ros/geometry
... fail tf2
```

Then tf2...

```
$ git clone https:// github.com/ros/geometry-experimental
$ cd ..
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --os=debian:wheezy
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
tf2_bullet: No definition of [bullet] for OS version [wheezy]
```

Okay, this is a new one for me, in progress...

**EDIT 3/13 See top**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126236/installing-rosserial-on-raspbian-with-ros-hydro/) by [Elucidation](https://answers.ros.org/users/11291/elucidation/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your install is calling for more dependencies than rosserial really needs, but I can't say why. FWIW you can install rosserial in a fresh "working" WS (e.g. ~/catkin_ws/ instead of your ~/ros_catkin_ws/) and just "catkin_make" it.

Here are instructions that worked for me, and a prebuilt Raspberry Pi image, too:

```
http://wiki.jigsawrenaissance.org/ROS_on_RaspberryPi
```

HTH

---

Originally posted by [cha](https://answers.ros.org/users/5989/cha/) with karma: 41 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elucidation](https://answers.ros.org/users/11291/elucidation/) on 2014-03-13**:
I followed the instructions (http://wiki.jigsawrenaissance.org/ROS_on_RaspberryPi) verbatim (used the official rosserial package) and it worked out perfectly, thanks cha!

**Comment by [michalgn](https://answers.ros.org/users/27868/michalgn/) on 2016-08-30**:
Hey, the website is no longer available, do you have another link that works?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's complaining that you don't have the nav_msgs package. I would find it and add it, or the stack that contains it, to your catkin workspace, and try again.

You'll probably have to repeat for a few more missing ROS dependencies.

*EDIT*

Bullet is a physics library. If you really need it, it can be obtained from https://code.google.com/p/bullet/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elucidation](https://answers.ros.org/users/11291/elucidation/) on 2014-02-04**:
I am aiming for rosserial communication between an arduino and a pi. It may be the rosserial is trying to cover all bases, I just need generics like odom and point etc., I'm not sure how to go about removing the un-needed dependency chain. dive into rabit hole and modify source?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-05**:
If you need odom, you need tf, which depends on tf2, which appears to depend on bullet. I'm not sure there's any way out of that hole other than to install the proper dependencies.